# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Razor Page show icon only if member of model is valid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor page that has a small registration form and it uses clientside validation via the jquery unobstrusive validation script. The error messages print fine and all but I wanted to style the form elements a bit more since I am already useing Bulma CSS.

Heres one of the fields

```cs
<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Username, null, new { @class = "label" })
    <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Username, new { @class = "input is-rounded" })
        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </span>
        @if (Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Username) == null) //always false even if the validation message at the bottom is not displayed
        {
            <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
            </span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
            </span>
        }
    </div>
    <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Username, "", new { @class = "help is-danger" })</p>
</div>
```

So my question now is how I can make the if..else work to show a nice checkmark if everythings alright and the danger symbol if its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a bit more digging and research I found a solution.

First I declare a new style block

```
<style>
    input.input-validation-error ~ span.invalid-icon {
        display: inline-flex !important;
    }
    input.input-validation-error ~ span.valid-icon {
        display: none !important;
    }
    input.valid ~ span.valid-icon {
        display: inline-flex !important;
    }
    input.valid ~ span.invalid-icon {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Then I made sure to place my icons next to the inputs like so

```
<div class=control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Username, new { @class = "input is-rounded has-background-" + colorMode + " has-text-" + textColor, @placeholder = "Username" })
    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="icon is-small is-right valid-icon" style="display: none;">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="icon is-small is-right invalid-icon" style="display: none;">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

So due to how bulma controls in forms work I can easily use the `~` CSS selector operator to select all `span` elements beside the `input` element that have the `valid-icon` or `invalid-icon` class. This in turn means I can use the automatically added/removed class of `input-validation-valid` and `input-validation-error` on the generated `input` tag to automatically show and hide the right icons.